# jsPDF addHTML get full contents of scrolling element

Tags: javascript, jspdf

How do I get jsPDF to create an image/pdf from an element that has overflow set so that it has scrollbars.  The following example pasted into the addHTML Have a Play page (http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/) will only generate a pdf for the section of the div that is showing, even if I choose the "middle" div:

```
var outer = document.createElement('div');
outer.style.height = "100px";
outer.style.overflow = "scroll";

var middle = document.createElement('div');

for ( var i=0; i<35;i++ ) {
    var inner = document.createElement('div');
    inner.style.border = "thick solid #0000ff";
    inner.style.padding = "10px";

    middle.appendChild(inner);
}

outer.appendChild(middle);
document.body.appendChild(outer);

var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');

pdf.addHTML(outer,function() {
    var string = pdf.output('datauristring');
    $('.preview-pane').attr('src', string);
});
```

(Basically, this is creating a div with a scrollbar, adding a div inside, then adding a whole bunch of divs inside the middle one.  There are enough to scroll off screen, so the pdf doesn't pick them up.  I thought of popping out a new window, but if I do that, I have to figure out all the different style sheets to pull into the popout.)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this discussion: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/270:

> I am using addHtml() method with html2canvas.js for making pdf , but for large data table it is not generating pdf ,for short content going fine. Please help me here is my code

To which Flamenco replies:

> I started working on a feature to breakup long HTML pages.
>
> Try This:
>   https://rawgit.com/Flamenco/jsPDF/text-html-table-page-break/examples/html2pdf/test-long-html-table.html

The example code creates a long table and generates a PDF with this. Perhaps his setup is of use to you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Long Table</title>
    </head>

<script src='../../libs/require/require.js'></script>
<script>
require_baseUrl_override = '../../';
require(['../../libs/require/config'], function(){
require(['jspdf.plugin.canvas', 'libs/html2pdf', 'libs/html2canvas/dist/html2canvas', 'libs/saveas'], function(){

var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a3');

// Enable auto page wrap (there are still margin-top issues...)
pdf.context2d.pageWrapY = pdf.internal.pageSize.height-20;

// create a long table
var table = document.createElement('table');
for (var i=1; i<1000; i++){
    var tr=document.createElement('tr');
    var td=document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = "Item " + i;
    tr.appendChild(td);
    table.appendChild(tr);
}
document.body.appendChild(table);

// render body to pdf
html2pdf(document.body, pdf, function(){
    pdf.save('Test.pdf');

});

}); // require
}); // require
</script>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code is a bit mangled, but it works.